# FCM MissingAuthorization issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

Here is my code:

```js
function sendToken(token) {
  $.ajax({
    url: 'https://iid.googleapis.com/iid/v1/' + token + '/rel/topics/IoT',
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      Authorization: 'key=' + server_key
    },
    contentType: 'application/json',
    cache: false,
    success: function(response) {
      console.log(response);
    },
    error: function(response) {
      console.log(response);
    }
  });
}
```

The response is `{"error":"MissingAuthorization"}`

I'm stuck and not able to understand why this is not working.

Comment: I'm guessing `server_key` is a variable, so you shouldn't be putting quotes around it

Comment: same response  {"error":"MissingAuthorization"}

Comment: The `Authorization` header should have this format: `'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + accessToken`, so use this in your code `Authorization: 'Bearer ' + server_key`. https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/auth-server#authorize_http_v1_send_requests

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same issue so I used fetch and it works.

```
fetch('https://iid.googleapis.com/iid/v1/'+token+'/rel/topics/'+topic, {
method: 'POST',
headers: new Headers({
  'Authorization': 'key='+server_key
})
}).then(response => {
    if (response.status < 200 || response.status >= 400) {
      throw 'Error subscribing to topic: '+response.status + ' - ' + response.text();
    }
    console.log('Subscribed to "'+topic+'"');
  }).catch(error => {
    console.error(error);
  })
```